# How to resolve COM server application local activation permission for machine account

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

I am trying to enable SSIS package logging to event logs. When an attempt is made to write to the event log the following error appears in the system event logs:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {806835AE-FD04-4870-A1E8-D65535358293}  and APPID 
>   {EE4171E6-C37E-4D04-AF4C-8617BC7D4914}  to the user DOMAIN\machine$
>   SID (S-1-5-21-16020293-282541685-632688529-241633) from address
>   LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using
>   the Component Services administrative tool.

I've dealt with this error before but the fact the error relates to a machine account has thrown me. Does this mean I have to specifically grant permissions to the machine account in component services? The app pool account running under the NETWORK SERVICE account.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate so. Why is this surprising to you? NETWORK SERVICE means that the service will try to access external resources using the machine account. In the DCOM config, it is not different from any other users.

Comment: The reason I am trying to ascertain if this is in fact the case is because I don't have the relevant permissions to add the machine account and thought I would clarify before asking someone else to do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @spaghettidba said, the error message is pretty clear. APPID EE4171E6-C37E-4D04-AF4C-8617BC7D4914 is Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0. It looks like you already knew what you had to do:

- Either grant access to the machine account in Component Services \ DCOM Config \Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0 (In properties \ Security \ Launch and Activation Permissions)
  or
- Change under which account the service request is being made.

Answer (score 0):

The log indicates that your database user (in your case DOMAIN\machine$) has permission issues. Try the following steps.

1. Launch `Component Services` (comexp.msc)
2. Expand `Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config`. Check View->Detail to have better visibility.
3. Locate `Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0` which has the AppId `{EE4171E6-C37E-4D04-AF4C-8617BC7D4914}`, select `Properties` from context menu and locate `Security` tab.
4. Edit `Launch and Activation Permissions`, allow your user for `Local Launch`, `Local Activation`. Do the same for `Access Permissions` as well.
5. Press Apply or OK. See if the problem gone. Fixed mine at least.